# Pandas: identify overlapping membership of a value within ranges

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a dataset that includes membership start and end dates (e.g., December 3, 2003 and October 23, 2007) and I am trying to isolate membership in each year (in above example I would be looking for 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007).

Right now my code will only identify membership in the first year, which isn't helpful since I could just get that by looking at the join year.

```
year_list = [2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009]

for year in year_list:

    mem_year_list = []

    for x in dfy.join_year:
        if x >= year | x < (year+1):
            mem_year_list.append(1)
        else:
            mem_year_list.append(0)
```

I feel like I may be missing a while statement but I haven't been able to figure it out and I wouldn't be surprised to find out that that wasn't the missing piece.

Data start like this:

```
mem_no  status  animal  join_year  exp_year         
00004   Active  Lark    12-2-02    10-23-07          
00101   Expired Parrot  4-1-03     2-1-16       
00118   Crunchy Frog    10-8-01    2-22-02      
00121   Grumpy  Panda   5-1-03     3-1-04
```

and end up looking like this:

```
mem_no  status  animal  join_year  exp_year  mem_02 mem_03 mem_04 mem_05    
00004   Active  Lark    12-2-02    10-23-07  1    0      0      0        
00101   Expired Parrot  4-1-03     2-1-16    0    1      0      0       
00118   Crunchy Frog    10-8-01    2-22-02   1    0      0      0       
00121   Grumpy  Panda   5-1-03     3-1-04    0    1      0      0
```

but I'd like it to end up like this:

```
mem_no  status  animal  join_year  exp_year  mem_02 mem_03 mem_04 mem_05    
00004   Active  Lark    12-2-02    10-23-07  1    1      1      1        
00101   Expired Parrot  4-1-03     2-1-16    0    1      1      1       
00118   Crunchy Frog    10-8-01    2-22-02   1    0      0      0       
00121   Grumpy  Panda   5-1-03     3-1-04    0    1      1      0
```

---

Roman gave a great answer that just needed a couple of tweaks:

```
dfy['joined'] = pd.to_datetime(dfy['joined'])
dfy['exp_date'] = pd.to_datetime(dfy['exp_date'])

year_list = [2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011,\
             2012, 2013, 2014, 2015]

for year in year_list:
# code to isolate prior years

    dfy['mem_' + str(year)] = dfy.apply(lambda x: x['joined'].year\
       <= year and x['exp_date'].year>= year, axis=1).astype('int')

# code to isolate current year

dfy['mem_2016'] = dfy.apply(lambda x: x['exp_date'].year\
       <= 2016, axis=1).astype('int')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> for year in year_list:
...     dfy['mem_' + str(year)] = dfy.apply(lambda x: x['join'].year <= year and x['end'].year >= year, axis=1).astype('int')
>>> dfy
   mem_no   status  animal       join        end  mem_2002  mem_2003  mem_2004  mem_2005  mem_2006  mem_2007  mem_2008  mem_2009
0       4   Active    Lark 2002-12-02 2007-10-23         1         1         1         1         1         1         0         0
1     101  Expired  Parrot 2003-04-01 2016-02-01         0         1         1         1         1         1         1         1
2     118  Crunchy    Frog 2001-10-08 2002-02-22         1         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
3     121   Grumpy   Panda 2003-05-01 2004-03-01         0         1         1         0         0         0         0         0
```

Comment: Thanks for sending this suggestion. Unfortunately it returned AttributeError: ("'int' object has no attribute 'year'", u'occurred at index 0')

Comment: well it looks like your `join` and `end` columns are not dates (terrible name for columns if you ask me :) ). So you can convert it with `df['join'] = pd.to_datetime(df['join'])`

Comment: the actual names are join_year and exp_year, fwiw, but I'll try converting to dt.

Comment: that change resulted in all 0s for the mem_years but tweaking it to make the datetime have dates and months did the trick.

Comment: FYI, it easy enough to fix with another formula for 2016, but the solution given indicated that there were new members having joined through 2040. 

This also showed that this year's numbers saw a huge drop rather than the (correct) gain since about a third of this year's members were assigned to out years and not to this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can first find all values between columns `join` and `end` with frequency `A` ('year') and [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) for reshape:

```
df1=pd.concat([pd.Series(r.Index, 
                         pd.date_range(r.join,r.end+pd.offsets.YearEnd(1), freq='A')) 
               for r in df.itertuples()]).reset_index()
df1.columns=[ 'years', 'index']
df1.years = df1.years.dt.year
df1['vals'] = 1
df1 = df1.pivot(index='index', columns='years', values='vals').fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df1)
years  2001  2002  2003  2004  2005  2006  2007  2008  2009  2010  2011  2012  \
index                                                                           
0         0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0   
1         0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1   
2         1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   
3         0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   

years  2013  2014  2015  2016  
index                          
0         0     0     0     0  
1         1     1     1     1  
2         0     0     0     0  
3         0     0     0     0
```

Then filter columns by years, [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) and [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) to original `DataFrame`:

```
year_list = [2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009]

df2 = pd.concat([df, 
                 df1[year_list].rename(columns=lambda x: str(x)[2:]).add_prefix('mem_')], 
                 axis=1)
print (df2)
  mem_no   status  animal       join        end  mem_02  mem_03  mem_04  \
0  00004   Active    Lark 2002-12-02 2007-10-23       1       1       1   
1  00101  Expired  Parrot 2003-04-01 2016-02-01       0       1       1   
2  00118  Crunchy    Frog 2001-10-08 2002-02-22       1       0       0   
3  00121   Grumpy   Panda 2003-05-01 2004-03-01       0       1       1   

   mem_05  mem_06  mem_07  mem_08  mem_09  
0       1       1       1       0       0  
1       1       1       1       1       1  
2       0       0       0       0       0  
3       0       0       0       0       0
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately I got back something REALLY weird, AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'month' (really weird because neither your code nor my data has 'month' in it).

Comment: First you need cast columns join and end to datetimes by `df['join']=pd.to_datetime(df['join'])` and `df['end']=pd.to_datetime(df['end'])` then my solution works perfectly.